# TCP/IP server using c

Tags: c, tcp, server

I want to make a server-client programm.The first thing i can't find is to make the server never shut down and accept each client.I put a while(1) on my server to run but after 3 connections to one client my server stops accepting other connections and i delete this while.I cant find how to build this think.Also i want to create TCP/IP socket so am i making the socket with the right way?

Im working on ubuntu at Visual Studio Code.

Server:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#define PORT 8080
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
struct sockaddr_in address; 
int opt = 1; 
int addrlen = sizeof(address); 

char *hello = "Hello from server";

    while(1){
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    printf("Server\n");
    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,&opt, 
    sizeof(opt))) { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address))<0) { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    if (listen(server_fd, 1) < 0) { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    printf("Listening...\n");
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,(socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
}
return 0;
}
```

My client so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

#define PORT 8080

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

char* command = (char*) malloc(15*sizeof(char));
int sock = 0, valread; 
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
char buffer[1024] = {0};

printf("Client\n");

if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){ 
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
    return -1; 
} 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

// Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  { 
    printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
    return -1; 
} 

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) { 
    printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
    return -1; 
}


send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
printf("%s\n",buffer ); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to show the non-working code (i.e. with `while` loop), so we can look for errors.

Comment: Yeah ok i put back my while

Comment: Fyi, in your server code, over half of that while-body doesn't belong there. It belongs *before* the while loop. The socket, the bind, the listen, all should be *prior* to the loop; the loop itself should be accepting, working with, and eventually closing accepted sockets.

Comment: **after 3 connections to one client my server stops accepting other connections** what does mean, are you getting "ECONNREFUSED" by server.

Comment: It didn't cause an error, it just stopped the client from connecting to the server.The server execution flow is frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the loop only around the code, which accepts the clients. The server socket itself is only created *once*.

```
// Creation of server socket(), bind(), listen()
while (1) {
   if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                              (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0) { 
       perror("accept"); 
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
   }

   valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
   printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
   send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
   printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
}
```

Furthermore, you should close the client socket at the end of the while block after the communication is finished (i.e. after the `printf("Hello message sent\n");`:

```
close(new_socket);
```

And note, that the clients are served serially this way. They can *connect* concurrently, but only one client is served at a time. If you need concurrent handling, you can for example `fork()` several processes, each handling one client, or handle multiple clients in one thread using `poll()` or `select()`.

Comment: I want to served one at the time so this is ok.And am i making the socket with the right way? This is TCP/IP socket?

Comment: @ΣωτηρηςΙωαννιδης Yes, you are creating a TCP server socket here.